# Puppet requires sudo permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

What on earth is going on with `puppet` on my Ubuntu node? It appears to be asking for `su` permissions to install stuff and I have no idea why it's doing this.

What can I do to make it work?

```
jay@scooter:~$ puppetd --test --server rizzo
info: Caching catalog for scooter
info: Applying configuration version '1331938939'
err: /Stage[main]//Node[scooter]/Package[apache2]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install apache2' returned 100: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you're not running Puppet as root, and you need root permissions to install packages via apt.  If you don't want it to install packages, then don't tell it to, and if you *do* want it to install packages, run it as root.  Also, it's not trying to run anything via `su` or `sudo`, it's just failing out in the usual way you'd get with anything that doesn't have the required file permissions.